# C programming: counts the number of characters, words and lines from another text file

Tags: c

I've just started learning C language and as the topic says, I have to write a code that will read another text file and count the number of "characters", "words" and "sentences" until `EOF` is reached. My current problems is that I'm not able to produce the right output.

For example a text file containing the following contents...

```
the world 
is a great place.
lovely
and wonderful
```

should output with 39 characters, 9 words and 4 sentences and somehow I get 50(characters) 1(words) 1(sentences)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int x;
char pos;
unsigned int long charcount, wordcount, linecount;

charcount = 0;
wordcount = 0;
linecount = 0;

while(pos=getc(stdin) != EOF)
{
    if (pos != '\n' && pos != ' ')
    {
    charcount+=1;
    }

    if (pos == ' ' || pos == '\n')
    {
    wordcount +=1;  
    }

    if (pos == '\n')
    {
    linecount +=1;
    }

}

    if (charcount>0)
    {
    wordcount+=1;
    linecount+=1;
    }

printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount );
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any sort of help or suggestion

Comment: With `char pos; ... while(pos=getc(stdin)`, better to use `int pos;` to distinguish the 257 different values returned by `fgetc()` - though I doubt this is your current problem,

Comment: Where do you open the file ?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to indicate that you're expecting the user to type the sample text into stdin, or remove stdin from the code.

Comment: If pos == `'\n'` is used twice in the if. You are counting words even though it might just be a new row.

Comment: Please note that a text file might not contain a final `newline`, you should take that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to operator precedence, the 2 below lines are the same.

```
// Not what OP needs
pos=getc(stdin) != EOF
pos=(getc(stdin) != EOF)
```

Instead, use `()`

```
while((pos=getc(stdin)) != EOF)
```

---

Use `int ch` to distinguish the values returned from `fgetc()` which are values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  Typically 257 different, too many for a `char`.

```
int main() {
  unsigned long character_count = 0;
  unsigned long word_count = 0;
  unsigned long line_count = 0;
  unsigned long letter_count = 0;
  int pos;

  while((pos = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    ...
```

---

You may want to review your word count strategy too. [@Tony Tannous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601168/c-programming-counts-the-number-of-characters-words-and-lines-from-another-tex/42601312#comment72333082_42601168)

---

For me, I would count a "word" as any time a letter occurred that did not follow a non-letter.  This avoids a problem [@Tony Tannous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6530695/tony-tannous) and other issues.  Like-wise, I would count a *line* as any character that followed a `'\n'` or the very first one and avoid any post loop calculation.  This handles the issue commented by [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601168/c-programming-counts-the-number-of-characters-words-and-lines-from-another-tex/42601312#comment72333323_42601168).

It also appear 39 is a *letter* count and not a character count [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601168/c-programming-counts-the-number-of-characters-words-and-lines-from-another-tex/42601312#comment72333325_42601168).
Suggest using `<ctype.h>` functions to test for letter-ness  (`isapha()`)

```
int previous = '\n';
while((pos = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
  character_count++;
  if (isalpha(pos)) {
    letter_count++;
    if (!isalpha(previous)) word_count++;
  }
  if (previous == '\n') line_count++;
  previous = pos;
}

printf("characters %lu\n", character_count);
printf("letters %lu\n", letter_count);
printf("words %lu\n", word_count);
printf("lines %lu\n", line_count);
```

Comment: With these two corrections the code gives `40 11 5` (with a final newline) and `40 10 4` (without a final newline) but the OP was expecting the output `39 9 4`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, OP's character (letter), line and word count need work too.  Suggest code posted.

Comment: Finally! But made difficult to copy/paste and compile with the inconsistent variable names.

Comment: @WeatherVane I choose different variable names to distinguish from OP's as the have subtle different definitions which I think is more in line with the true coding goals.

Comment: @WeatherVane Further I wanted to avoid OP from simply cut/paste.  to notice the differences.

Comment: I got it! Those suggestions really helped thanks guys!!